# Build x86 ImageMagick application on x86_64 linux system

Tags: c++, imagemagick, centos7, magick++

I have x86 C++ application which using ImageMagic++ library. I also have machine with CentOS 7 x86_64. I need to build my application on this machine.
I have installed i686 ImageMagick library:

```
[dvoryankin@testsuitel]$ yum list installed | grep Magick
 ImageMagick.i686                   6.7.8.9-10.el7                      @base    
 ImageMagick-c++.i686               6.7.8.9-10.el7                      @base    
 ImageMagick-c++-devel.i686         6.7.8.9-10.el7                      @base    
 ImageMagick-devel.i686             6.7.8.9-10.el7                      @base
```

When I try to build my application I have an error:

```
/usr/include/ImageMagick/magick/magick-config.h:9:31:
fatal error: magick-config-64.h: No such file or directory
    #include "magick-config-64.h"
```

It's happened becuase file */usr/include/ImageMagick/magick/magick-config.h* use macro definition `__WORDSIZE` to determine which file must be included *magick-config-64.h* or *magick-config-32.h*. On my machine with CentOS 7 x86_64 this macro is equal 64 and ImageMagick try to include *magick-config-64.h* but i686 library doesn't have this, only *magick-config-32.h*.

How I can build x86 application with x86 ImageMagick library on CentOS 7 x86_64 machine without change any library files?

Comment: Have you done `yum install ImageMagick-devel`

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, i have installed ImageMagick-devel.i686

Comment: Have you tried the latest releases? After all, your version is around 2+ years old and we are now on 6.9.2-3

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can't select OS and it version. I just have access to already made environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only suggest rebuilding ImageMagick & delegates in an isolated location (not `/usr/` directory).

```
curl -O http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar zvxf ImageMagick.tar.gz && cd ImageMagick-6.9.2-4
CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 \
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/opt/im32
```

Provided you have everything you need for [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) to build cross-platform, and you already have all ImageMagick dependencies built in `x86`.

The utility `/opt/im32/bin/Magick++-config` can be used to print out the additional compiler/linker flags need for your [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to define  __WORDSIZE in command line like
CXXFLAGS='-D __WORDSIZE=64' 
before configure